# How do I scrape data from this webpage with python using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-beautifultable

How do I scrape data from this webpage with python using BeautifulSoup? I'm specifically trying to get the last table which includes data of all neighborhoods.

https://www.zolo.ca/toronto-real-estate/neighbourhoods

Comment: Please share what you have tried and explain what didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to load the data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
}

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.zolo.ca/toronto-real-estate/neighbourhoods", headers=headers
)

df = pd.read_html(r.text)[-1]

df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(r"(\d+)(.*)", r"\1 \2")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          Neighbourhood (# Rank out of 143) Sold under 10d Sold above asking Average sale price  Active listings
0                        19 Agincourt North            72%               73%              $951K               25
1           71 Agincourt South-Malvern West            53%               60%              $692K               42
2                              59 Alderwood            63%               53%              $1.3M               30
3                                 141 Annex            31%               20%              $1.5M              129
4                     107 Banbury-Don Mills            46%               36%              $1.3M               55
5                         80 Bathurst Manor            51%               51%              $1.3M               16
6                   142 Bay Street Corridor            28%               19%              $777K              154
7                       113 Bayview Village            42%               38%              $834K               72
8                  66 Bayview Woods-Steeles            60%               48%              $1.3M                9
9                   91 Bedford Park-Nortown            54%               34%              $2.4M               57
10                5 Beechborough-Greenbrook            86%               86%              $982K                5
11                               64 Bendale            58%               58%              $766K               30
12                 63 Birchcliffe-Cliffside            58%               59%              $1.0M               40
13                          112 Black Creek            40%               45%              $550K                6
14                           10 Blake-Jones            82%               73%              $1.3M                6
15                  70 Briar Hill-Belgravia            56%               50%              $812K               13
16    140 Bridle Path-Sunnybrook-York Mills            31%               21%              $4.4M               53
17                       42 Broadview North            67%               57%              $1.1M                6
18                  134 Brookhaven-Amesbury            33%               33%              $853K               11
19      83 Cabbagetown-South St. James Town            53%               45%              $1.2M               20
20                    45 Caledonia-Fairbank            63%               67%              $988K               12
21                            108 Casa Loma            45%               34%              $1.7M               36
22                11 Centennial Scarborough            80%               75%              $1.1M                8
23                135 Church-Yonge Corridor            35%               28%              $706K              172
24                    9 Clairlea-Birchmount            78%               89%              $919K               13
25                          96 Clanton Park            47%               47%              $1.0M               36
26                            35 Cliffcrest            68%               66%              $1.3M               19
27                47 Corso Italia-Davenport            63%               63%              $1.2M               18
28                        114 Crescent Town            44%               32%              $566K               16
29                               8 Danforth            84%               74%              $1.3M                6
30             6 Danforth Village-East York            85%               76%              $1.3M               16
31                   105 Don Valley Village            49%               33%              $994K               25
32                           73 Dorset Park            51%               60%              $731K               20
33   38 Dovercourt-Wallace Emerson-Junction            69%               57%              $1.1M               41
34                  89 Downsview-Roding-CFB            50%               48%              $869K               64
35                        30 Dufferin Grove            70%               67%              $1.1M                9
36                     24 East End-Danforth            73%               67%              $1.1M               13
37                              7 East York            84%               76%              $1.4M               12
38             136 Edenbridge-Humber Valley            37%               22%              $1.5M               31
39                         51 Eglinton East            60%               71%              $756K               14
40                     143 Elms-Old Rexdale            15%               30%              $561K               10
41                   77 Englemount-Lawrence            55%               42%              $1.2M               27
42        44 Eringate-Centennial-West Deane            66%               58%              $1.1M               15
43                  103 Etobicoke West Mall            45%               45%              $745K               16
44                      132 Flemingdon Park            33%               36%              $591K               31
45                     68 Forest Hill North            60%               40%              $1.8M                9
46                    121 Forest Hill South            41%               34%              $2.3M               29
47                40 Glenfield-Jane Heights            65%               63%              $821K               14
48                     20 Greenwood-Coxwell            71%               74%              $1.3M               21
49                             18 Guildwood            72%               76%              $996K               16
50                           119 Henry Farm            42%               35%              $633K               40
51                       81 High Park North            53%               44%              $1.2M               16
52                     94 High Park-Swansea            48%               47%              $1.2M               23
53                        27 Highland Creek            73%               64%              $1.4M               20
54                     16 Hillcrest Village            76%               76%              $1.1M               25
55                        85 Humber Heights            55%               36%              $869K               22
56                         87 Humber Summit            50%               50%              $794K                9
57                1 Humberlea-Pelmo Park W4           100%              100%              $942K                5
58               32 Humberlea-Pelmo Park W5            68%               71%              $942K               10
59                            95 Humbermede            45%               55%              $673K                8
60                    53 Humewood-Cedarvale            65%               55%              $1.5M                4
61                               50 Ionview            57%               79%              $824K                7
62                                Islington             0%                0%                 $0                2
63           111 Islington-City Centre West            42%               41%              $822K               65
64                         34 Junction Area            67%               72%              $1.0M                9
65              86 Keelesdale-Eglinton West            48%               57%              $886K               13
66                          54 Kennedy Park            62%               59%              $889K               16
67                 139 Kensington-Chinatown            29%               32%              $849K               37
68        106 Kingsview Village-The Westway            46%               40%              $772K               33
69                       118 Kingsway South            42%               35%              $2.3M               21
70                            37 L'Amoreaux            65%               72%              $853K               36
71                    23 Lambton Baby Point            71%               71%              $1.7M                4
72                     131 Lansing-Westgate            35%               31%              $1.2M               30
73                   61 Lawrence Park North            61%               53%              $1.9M               10
74                   41 Lawrence Park South            71%               45%              $3.1M               31
75                               72 Leaside            57%               43%              $2.1M               28
76                       97 Little Portugal            48%               43%              $809K               33
77                           69 Long Branch            58%               45%              $979K               23
78                               58 Malvern            58%               65%              $662K               51
79                           101 Maple Leaf            47%               41%              $1.2M               11
80                         98 Markland Wood            48%               41%              $850K               10
81                              33 Milliken            66%               75%              $860K               27
82                                99 Mimico            48%               40%              $800K              131
83                           46 Morningside            59%               76%              $757K               10
84                             93 Moss Park            50%               43%              $731K               53
85                         110 Mount Dennis            35%               61%              $666K               18
86    128 Mount Olive-Silverstone-Jamestown            33%               39%              $557K               21
87                   76 Mount Pleasant East            55%               45%              $1.4M               34
88                  133 Mount Pleasant West            35%               29%              $780K               66
89                           48 New Toronto            63%               63%              $1.2M               11
90                     120 Newtonbrook East            45%               25%              $1.6M               44
91                      88 Newtonbrook West            52%               43%              $1.1M               60
92                               92 Niagara            49%               44%              $754K               78
93                       21 North Riverdale            70%               78%              $1.8M                7
94                 125 North St. James Town            36%               36%              $790K                8
95                     43 O'Connor-Parkview            67%               57%              $1.4M               12
96                              36 Oakridge            69%               62%              $948K                8
97                       39 Oakwood-Vaughan            69%               54%              $1.1M               25
98               60 Palmerston-Little Italy            67%               39%              $1.3M                9
99                     74 Parkwoods-Donalda            52%               55%              $951K               29
100             14 Playter Estates-Danforth            80%               70%              $1.6M                1
101                        67 Pleasant View            56%               60%              $907K               11
102                   28 Princess-Rosethorn            73%               64%              $1.8M                8
103                          90 Regent Park            51%               43%              $714K               19
104                      26 Rexdale-Kipling            70%               73%              $916K                9
105                    79 Rockcliffe-Smythe            51%               54%              $941K               22
106                         29 Roncesvalles            72%               65%              $1.4M               22
107                 124 Rosedale-Moore Park            42%               24%              $2.1M               73
108                             2 Rouge E10            94%               94%              $1.0M                7
109                            22 Rouge E11            68%               81%              $914K               24
110          3 Runnymede-Bloor West Village            91%               82%              $1.6M                7
111                               12 Rustic            71%              100%              $1.0M                8
112                  84 Scarborough Village            47%               61%              $930K               28
113                      100 South Parkdale            46%               46%              $1.0M                5
114                      25 South Riverdale            72%               69%              $1.1M               52
115               102 St. Andrew-Windfields            48%               36%              $2.6M               55
116                              49 Steeles            63%               63%              $1.1M               24
117                  78 Stonegate-Queensway            53%               48%              $1.3M               33
118               56 Tam O'Shanter-Sullivan            61%               62%              $857K               18
119                          15 The Beaches            80%               70%              $1.7M               43
120        65 Thistletown-Beaumonde Heights            57%               57%              $1.1M                8
121                    138 Thorncliffe Park            36%               18%              $592K                2
122                   104 Trinity-Bellwoods            44%               46%              $1.6M               21
123                          116 University            44%               29%              $1.2M               17
124                     31 Victoria Village            71%               63%              $940K               11
125           123 Waterfront Communities C1            41%               29%              $727K              377
126           130 Waterfront Communities C8            35%               31%              $802K               87
127                            57 West Hill            60%               65%              $849K               35
128              117 West Humber-Clairville            41%               38%              $695K               27
129                 115 Westminster-Branson            41%               40%              $766K               27
130                               62 Weston            58%               60%              $770K               16
131                   75 Weston-Pellam Park            53%               53%              $979K               10
132                     55 Wexford-Maryvale            62%               60%              $990K               21
133                     126 Willowdale East            36%               32%              $893K              139
134                     122 Willowdale West            42%               32%              $1.1M               44
135     52 Willowridge-Martingrove-Richview            63%               63%              $1.1M               19
136                               82 Woburn            50%               54%              $746K               36
137                    13 Woodbine Corridor            79%               79%              $1.2M                4
138                      4 Woodbine-Lumsden            86%               86%              $1.1M                8
139                             17 Wychwood            78%               63%              $1.4M                8
140                      109 Yonge-Eglinton            44%               38%              $1.5M               15
141                     137 Yonge-St. Clair            36%               23%              $1.6M               33
142             129 York University Heights            34%               33%              $833K               23
143                  127 Yorkdale-Glen Park            36%               33%              $802K               43
```

Comment: This method no longer works. Now it returns status_code '403'.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this link i think it would solve your problem.

https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-scraping-table-data-1665b6b2271c